# How to sort the whole worksheet from another worksheet on button click event using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to sort the wohole sheet on particular column on button click event usig VBA. I am dynamically creating worksheet (Output) on button click event from Source worksheet ("Rawdata").
I have written the code for sorting the column "G" or "Report Date" from the source sheet and output data sheet is not sorted as expecting . I don't know why ?

My code for sorting :

```
Dim Output_Sh As Worksheet
Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rawdata") 
Data_sh.Range("A1").Sort Key1:=Range("G1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

How to sort the one worksheet on the bases of particular column condition.

Source Worksheet (Rawdata) :
[image]

I want to implement the sorting procedure in the below module

```
  Sub ModuleProcess_Data()
    
    Dim Data_sh As Worksheet
    Dim Filter_Criteria As Worksheet
    Dim Output_Sh As Worksheet
    
    
    'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Worksheets("Output").Delete
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Output"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rawdata")  ' ** Read the Data from here **
    Set Output_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")   ' **  Output Sheet **
    
    Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    '---- Other functionality
    
    '**** Sorting the output worksheet on the bases of column "G" on source worksheet
    Data_sh.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Data_sh.Range("A1").Sort Key1:=Range("G1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes


    Data_sh.UsedRange.Copy Output_Sh.Range("A1")
    
    Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    End Sub
```

Output Sheet (Not sorting as expected)

[image]

Comment: First thing i notice is your unqualified range... It should be `Data_sh.Range("A1").Sort Key1:=Data_sh.Range("G1")` - It does not automatically assume you are referencing the same sheet like you seem to think it does.

Comment: Also comment out the `On Error Resume Next` to see if one of the following lines is throwing an error.